# Border-radius недостаточно круглый

Tags: border, css

Вот так выглядит кнопка на моём сайте:

[image]

А вот так на инбоксе:

[image]

Обе скруглены вот так Border-radius: 50%;
Тэг используется button.

Почему у меня скругление попиксельное, что у них за сглаживание такое?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uj7g6rjc/
у меня получилось вот так. Покажите код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блин, я на куралесил, всё в порядке, просто кнопку вставил в повторяющийся элемент, и сгенерировалось несколько штук в одном месте, исправил - и всё стало гладеньким. )